# newman is throwing memory error for around 600 requests

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I am facing some memory issue while using **htmlextra** as reporting tool for my newman collection executions. I selected this tool as it separates every iterations and publish the report in more clear way. I am trying to execute around **1500-2000** requests at once. (Any other recommended collection runner to avoid this issue?)
Below is the error which I am getting.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[7188:00000222C42684C0] 50386366 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4095.1 (4120.9) -> 4089.2 (4116.4) MB, 62.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 94.0 ms in 36 steps since start of marking, biggest step 32.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 253 ms) (average mu = 0.393, current mu = 0[7188:00000222C42684C0] 50386374 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4092.3 (4118.9) -> 4092.0 (4118.9) MB, 0.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.393, current mu = 0.508) allocation failure;
    
    <--- JS stacktrace --->
    
        FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
        1: 00007FF7753F07BF node_api_throw_syntax_error+175823
        2: 00007FF775375796 DSA_meth_get_flags+59654
        3: 00007FF775377480 DSA_meth_get_flags+67056
        4: 00007FF775E1E944 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+116
        5: 00007FF775E09CD2 v8::Isolate::Exit+674
        6: 00007FF775C8BB8C v8::internal::EmbedderStackStateScope::ExplicitScopeForTesting+124
        7: 00007FF775C98E6D v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1117
        8: 00007FF775C95EF7 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3367
        9: 00007FF775C88627 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2039
        10: 00007FF775C9EFE3 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath+2099
        11: 00007FF775C9F88D v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath+93
        12: 00007FF775CA81BF v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+783
        13: 00007FF775CBB58D v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewHeapNumber<0>+685
        14: 00007FF775CBFA38 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString+72
        15: 00007FF775A67384 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten+724
        16: 00007FF775992794 v8::internal::DeclarationScope::was_lazily_parsed+35108
        17: 00007FF775EBBE71 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
        18: 00007FF775EAC9B4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+495540
        19: 00007FF6F6414BC2
```

Comment: I have found some similar issues online but couldn't find specific solution for this. Here are few of them which I went through:

Issue [#2712][1]
Issue [#941][2]
Issue [#935][3]
Issue [#2483][4]


  [1]: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2712
  [2]: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/941
  [3]: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/935
  [4]: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2483